# can not open gnome-terminal in normal user mode from root user mode

Tags: command-line

When I issue "gnome-terminal" command as a root user it is opening a new terminal in root user mode only. Now my question is that "Is there any way to open a new terminal in normal user mode even when we issue 'gnome-terminal' command from root user mode?"

"'xyz#' gnome-terminal"
       should open a new terminal with "xyz:~$" prompt.

Comment: Just click Ctrl + Alt + T as when terminal is working as root it doesn't expect to be launching a Terminal window for another user (you!)

Answer (score 1):

Use *su* , and log in with your account:

```
su - yourUserName -c 'gnome-terminal'
```

As an alternative, you may use the *runuser*  command:

```
runuser -l  yourUserName -c 'gnome-terminal'
```

Comment: That's not what `runuser` is for.  Use `su` or `sudo`.